# 2 MouseListeners at the same location in a layeredPane

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a JLayeredPane 'lp' which contains a JPanel 'p' with a JLabel 'l' on it.

If the label is clicked then I print out the message 'label1 was clicked' and then add another JPanel 'p2' to the JLayeredPane 'lp' on top of 'p', with another JLabel on 'p2' say 'l2'.

If the label 'l2' is clicked it should print out 'label2 was clicked'.

The Labels l1 & l2 overlap each other on the LayeredPane. On running, when l is clicked, it displays 'p2' with 'l2' but after that if 'l2' is clicked, it does not say 'label2 was clicked'. Instead it just keeps saying 'label1 was clicked' and keeps adding more and more panels.

Here is an MCVE which demonstrates the problem..

1. Main class

   ```
       package com.company;

       public class Main {

           public static void main(String[] args) {
               Frame f = new Frame();
               f.setVisible(true);
           }
       }
   ```
2. Frame class

   ```
       package com.company;

       import javax.swing.*;
       import java.awt.*;
       import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
       import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

       public class Frame extends JFrame {
           MouseAdapter listener;

           public Frame()
           {
               super.setSize(600,600);
               super.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

               JLayeredPane layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
               layeredPane.setSize(600, 600);

               listener = new MouseAdapter() {
                   @Override
                   public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                       System.out.println("Label1 was clicked");

                       JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
                       panel2.setBackground(Color.RED);
                       panel2.setBounds(270,0,60,60);

                       JLabel label2 = new JLabel("LABEL 2");
                       label2.setBounds(0,0,60,60);
                       panel2.add(label2);

                       layeredPane.add(panel2, 2);
                       label2.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                           @Override
                           public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                               System.out.println("Label 2 was clicked.");
                           }
                       });
                   }
               };

               JPanel panel1 = new Panel(layeredPane);

               JLabel label1 = new JLabel("LABEL 1");
               label1.setBounds(0,0,60,60);
               panel1.add(label1);
               label1.addMouseListener(listener);

               layeredPane.add(panel1, 1);

               super.add(layeredPane);
               super.validate();
           }
       }
   ```
3. Panel class

   ```
       package com.company;

       import javax.swing.*;
       import java.awt.*;

       public class Panel extends JPanel {
           JLayeredPane layeredPane;

           public Panel(JLayeredPane layeredPane) {
               this.layeredPane = layeredPane;

               super.setSize(600,600);
               super.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

           }
       }
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you ran into a "common layered pane problem" as the Oracle docs page says. So use an Integer and not an int:

```java
layeredPane.add(panel2, new Integer(2));
```

and

```java
layeredPane.add(panel1, new Integer(1));
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/problems.html#layeredpane

Comment: Thanks it worked... Although, my IDE says "Deprecated". Who cares as long as it works.